# Configurator class not found Exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging, log4j

I created custom logger library by using apache log4j library. Now I using my logger library in another maven project instead of apache log4j library. when I running the project it throwing an Exception that is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configurator
    at com.slice.slicelog4j.service.LogManager.initialize(LogManager.java:95)
    at com.slice.slicelog4j.service.LogManager.<init>(LogManager.java:21)
    at com.slice.slicelog4j.service.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:29)
```

because my custom logger library internally using the apache log4j library, but my maven project where I'm using my own logger library don't not have apache log4j libraries it only have my custom library.
Anyone can tell me how should I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying that log4j is **not** a transitive dependency in your logger library, rather the log4j source is part of it?

Comment: Yes, what should I do to solve it? I even adding the required libraries when I'm converting my logger library into jar, but it is showing same error.